# jQuery CSS doesn't work to set Top position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

Please give a look on the above screenshot of Chrome console. Though 1st line of jQuery code should change the "Top Position" of "#footer" DIV to 1426px,  `jQuery("#footer").position().top`  is showing as 1401 only. Its Top is expected to 1426, but shown as 1401. Please let me know if you understand its underlying causes.

Comment: Try with [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), to get the position relative to the document.

Comment: Is your footer positioned absolute or relative?

Comment: Footer position property was not set. After defining it to "absolute", it has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved! Explanation: The "position" CSS property of #footer element was not defined, so by default, it would become "static". To solve this issue, I had to change its "position" property to "absolute".

Answer (score 0):

`.top` only gives you number not unit. But `top` expects some unit `px` or `em` or `%`

So, do this:

```
jQuery('#footer').css("top", jQuery('#pager').position().top + 40 + "px");
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. jQuery('#footer').css("top", $('#pager').position().top + "px") returns 1401px, though it is expected as 1426px.

Comment: yes, I checked. Though it should be jQuery("#footer").css("top", (jQuery("#pager").position().top + 40) + "px"). If you give a look on 1st line of console screenshot, you can see it returns 'Style="top: 1426px;".

Comment: Doesn't have to specify 'px', jQuery set it by it self. The problem is elsewhere. @Agilox can you provide the code or demo for this?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$top=jQuery('#pager').css('top');
if($top.match(/^-/g)){
    $top= '-'+parseInt($top.replace(/\D/g,''));
}
else{
    $top= parseInt($top.replace(/\D/g,''));
    }
$top=$top+40
jQuery('#footer').css("top",  $top + "px");
```

or if you position the #pager element by margins, you have to use `$top=jQuery('#pager').css('margin-top');`